# List View Permissions

Tags: list, view, permissions, sharepoint-2013

I'm trying to create a new view off an existing list. However I dont want this list to be visible to the public just a few people. I have already created to new list I just haven't had much luck with the permissions.

Comment: Show the code you tried so far

Comment: @jxpython I haven't put any code in I was hoping that it was an out of the box fix. What code do you suggest?

Answer (score 0):

Please check below steps.

This is possible by using audience targeting feature. Create as many view as you want and bind all views one by one in list AllItems view(Allitems.aspx).  While adding the view in AllItems page you have to do the audience targeting. Below are details steps.

1. Create view A, B, C foe list TestList
2. Create user group X, Y, Z
3. Open the TestList, bu default all items will display in AllItems.aspx page
4. Edit the page by using Site Action
5. Click on the Modify Shared Web Part link of TestList . Now select the View A from selected dropdown
6. Go to Advanced section and select user group in the target audience. Apply the changes
7. Add the TestList web part again to the same AllItems.aspx page.
8. Repeat the step 5 and 6 for other two views and set the target audience respectively.
9. Now the AllItems.aspx page will have three web part for one list i.e TestList

Reference: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/3730d47f-6ba2-4ffd-ac05-567b042ff5c1/how-to-restrict-permissions-on-list-views?forum=sharepointgenerallegacy